# Ask administrator permission when entering a form

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms in my application. Form 1 is my start-up form where I don't want the user to be asked for administrator permissions. However when entering form 2 I want my application to ask for administrator permissions. Is this possible in vb.net 2012?

Comment: What kind of administrator permissions? You want your program to make its decision off of the Windows log in user's credential? Or could you simply just make a password box and have everything on the form disabled until they input the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. UAC is at the process level.